# AdWords to GoogleAds v9: UserList selectors and building a list of UserList's (UserListPage in Adwords)

Tags: port, google-ads-api

I can't figure out what is used to mimic the UserListPage and Selector behavior from Adwords in Google Ads. If anyone knows the proper classes to use I'd appreciate it. I am trying to retrieve a list of user lists with specific conditions, to then feed the userlist id,name and eligible into an Audience list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I belive you're looking for [UserListService](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/reference/rpc/v9/UserListService).
Here's an example provided for creating and managing a list https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-python/blob/main/examples/remarketing/add_customer_match_user_list.py

You might also make a search query to retrieve a specific user list like

```
SELECT user_list.id, user_list.type, user_list.name FROM user_list
```